# Approximation of rectifiable sets

Tags: geometric-measure-theory

Let us say that I have a $H^d$ measurable, $H^d$ finite set $E \subset \mathbf{R}^n$ such that there exists a sequence of $C^1$ submanifold $(S_i)$ of $\mathbf{R}^n$ such that
\begin{equation}
H^d(E \setminus \bigcup_i S_i) = 0.
\end{equation}
Then is it true that for $H^d$-a.e. $x \in E$, there exists an index $i$ such that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{r \to 0} r^{-d} H^d(B(x,r) \cap (E \Delta S_i))=0 \ ?
\end{equation}
Here $\Delta$ is the symmetric difference, i.e.
\begin{equation}
(E \Delta S) = (E \setminus S) \cup (S \setminus E).
\end{equation}